# Does Verifying Tokens with Firebase App Check Count Towards the API Request Quota?

Tags: python, quota, firebase-app-check, google-play-integrity-api

I'm currently implementing Firebase App Check in my application and have a question about API request quotas. The Firebase documentation mentions a limit of **10,000 total requests per day** across all installs for **Google Play Integrity API**. However, I'm unclear on which operations count towards this limit, specifically in the context of token verification.

I understand that obtaining a token is an API request, but I'm uncertain if verifying the token in my backend also counts as an API request. Here's a snippet of my code using the Python SDK of Firebase App Check:

```
from firebase_admin import app_check
from firebase_admin import credentials

cred = credentials.Certificate("my_cert_file.json")
firebase_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
app_check_token = "my-app-check-token"
app_check_claims = app_check.verify_token(app_check_token)
```

**My main question is:** Does the verify_token function make an API request that counts towards our daily quota?

In my research, I found this [GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/2014) issue stating that "Obtaining the Firebase App Check public JSON Web Key Set is the only outgoing request for the app check verify token API". Further examination of the [Firebase Admin Python SDK](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-python) repository showed that a request is made to "https://firebaseappcheck.googleapis.com/v1/jwks" to obtain the RSA public keys.

However, I'm still unsure if this operation impacts our daily API request quota. Clarity on this matter is crucial for designing the workflows.

I would appreciate it if anyone with certain knowledge about this could help me.